# In .bashrc how to use the output of "uname -m" as path (I get error: "uname: No such file or directory")?

Tags: command-line, bashrc

In my `$HOME/.bashrc` I defined the following variable:

```
ARCH="uname -m"
```

Calling from the terminal:

```
$ARCH
```

I'd like to get:

```
x86_64
```

and I get as I'd like:

```
x86_64
```

But calling:

```
local/$ARCH
```

I'd like to get:

```
local/x86_64
```

and I get:

```
local/uname: No such file or directory --> =(
```

Does anybody know what to change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a [command substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html) - `$(...)`. As example:

```
echo "local/$($ARCH)"
```

But, if you use only:

```
local/$($ARCH)
```

you will get again an error if `local/x86_64` is not an executabile file